# How to scale a background image to cover, times an extra scaling factor?

Tags: css, background-size

I have a background image which I would like to cover the element, using `background-size: cover;` However, I'd also like to scale it up 110% in both directions, *beyond* what `cover` does, so that I can subsequently move it around with `background-position`.

Put another way, I'd like `background-size: cover` to treat the surrounding div as if it were 110% larger in both directions.

Is there a way to do this purely in CSS?

If I understand correctly, this would be a way to do it, but `max()` is not standard CSS3:

```
background-size: max(auto 110%) max(auto 110%);
```

Comment: do you want the image to take up the whole screen? ex. 100% width and height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/2z2aw5u0/) for you to check out. I believe I understood the question correctly but please let me know if I am off base.

I wrapped the div that has the `background-image` in another div like so:

```
<div class="hero-container">
    <div class="row" id="hero"></div>
</div>
```

and applied the styles like so:

```
.hero-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#hero {
    background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110vh;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Play around with the fiddle by changing the `height: 110vh` and let me know if this is what you were looking for, or if I am at least on the right track.

Hope this helps!

EDIT*: I removed the transition and the padding as these are not necessary.

If you would like to do this with a container that has a fixed height you can change the `.hero-container` height to 500px or something and then just use 110% instead of 110vh in the height for the `#hero` div.

Comment: I forked your fiddle and was playing around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/tq2mn8ad/ I think this the simplest way to get what I want. I was hoping to do it without an extra div, but if no-one comes up with a better answer I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: I'm glad I could help at least a little bit. I just found that doing it this way would be compatible and still very simple.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understood your question correctly, I guess you can try this below:

```css
.box {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```